# How can I avoid both objects A and B using class C (or is it unavoidable)?

Tags: object-oriented, python, networking, event-programming

I have the following setup:

- An object A running as a separate service with its own address (implemented via Pyro package in Python).
- An object B running as a separate service with its own address.
- Object C used as a vehicle to transport data between A and C.

Use case:

- A creates C and sends it to B for processing.

What annoys me:

- I need to import C class definition in both A and B.

Main question:

- Is this normal? Do I really need to have C in some common library? Would that not be a problem if A is sitting on one server, B on another and the common library (with C) changes?

Side question:

- I am going for some hybrid of object orientated and event driven system. Does this setup sound like it? I am not too familiar with the terminology for paradigms. Is this service based architecture?

Comment: I can't follow your concern. Do you think that in a distributed system, the server and client should have *no classes* in common? That's quite a radical strategy. I don't think I've ever seen a distributed system where they didn't share at least basic utility functions.

Comment: A and B are both working with C, so they should both know about it. Think of C as for example some JSON string. It's just a data container but both need to know about it.

Comment: @Kilian Foth It just seems to make the system vulnerable and the components not totally decoupled. Say common library C is sitting on both A and B. Say A has the newest version of C, B has an older version of C -- problem waiting to happen.

Comment: Yes. If your two components want to talk to each other, they need to agree on a common language. There's no way around that. If one of the two suddenly decides to speak a different language (or in your problem example a different version of the language), then they can't communicate. If I had written this text in Middle English instead of Modern English, you wouldn't have understood it either.

Comment: What people are trying to tell you here is: no, you don't need a "common library" for communication between A and B. Both could agree on communication using an interface specification which is based on strings (maybe XML or JSON strings), which are passed by a common protocol like `http`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I talk to you I have to import a concept called English.  It annoys me that you have to import English as well because there are all these interesting French women who refuse to import English.  I'd like to be able to talk to them but I refuse to import French as well.

You need some common way to communicate.  You could send a string but even that requires a common way to communicate.  You'd just be using the fact that both have already imported string. Of course you'd still have to decide what the string will be (json, xml, ini, ...) and how it's structured (schema) so really you're right back where you started.

Another design would be to create a C interface that only defined what needs to be common.  That way B doesn't care about C other then how to talk to it leaving A free to create as many different kinds of C implementations as it likes.

Alternately you could use the UN model and create class D whose job it is to translate AC's into BC's and vise versa.  This is a lot of extra work so understand this is a work around that only makes sense because neither side totally won the Anglo-French Wars.

Answer (score 1):

It's not uncommon but it's no the only, or necessarily best, way.

Two common alternatives that spring to mind:

1. Client Stub
2. Message Broker

**Client Stub**

In this model, one object, say A, communicates with a very thin layer whose only job is to forward the data to the other object. It should just have data marshalling and networking code and that's it.

Any logic in the transportation should all be bundled in the other end, the *server* side. The advantage is that you only ever need to change the stub if the structure of the data changes. If you're careful, you can write so that you rarely, if ever, need to change this code.

**Message Broker**

This extends the Client Stub idea and has stubs at both ends. You then need a 3rd process to handle the interaction. It's more complex and has more failure modes but has the advantage of almost complete decoupling of you functionality from your message transport.

It's useful if the transport logic is complex and/or you need to send the data to more than one receiver object.